# cannot get value from $_post

Tags: php, jquery, post, jquery-1.8

I have an question about my code.

I use $ post to send the array to do.insert_php.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#submit_button').click(function(){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Process this form?")){
            var form=$('#form2').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:"do/do_insert.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:form,
                success:function(){
                    $('#form2')[0].reset();
                    alert('Process Success');
                } 
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and then looping the value in the do_insert process.

```
foreach($_GET["contract"] as $k=>$val1){
//code here
}
```

this is my dynamic field for contract.

```
$data1 = json_decode($_POST['myData']);
//$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
if (is_array($data1) || is_object($data1))
{
    $count = 0;
    echo "<tr id='row'> ";
    foreach($data1 as $mydata){
        $count++;

        //echo "<td width='197'><input type='text' id='contract.".$mydata->Id."' name= 'contract[]' value='".$mydata->Id."'/></td>";
        echo "<td width='197'><input type='hidden' id='contract.".$mydata."' name= 'contract[]' value='".$mydata."'/></td>";


   }
   echo "</tr> ";
   echo "<tr id='row'> ";
   echo "<td width='197'>Total Record</td>";
   echo "<td width='197'><input type='text' id='total' name= 'total' value='".$count."'/></td>";
   echo "</tr> ";
}
```

my form

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST">
<td><input name='submit_button' type='button' id='submit_button' value='Submit' class='btn'/></td>
<table id="dynamic_field">

</table>


</form>
```

the question is, when I use $_get in the do_insert.php,the process will be running, but when I change it into $_post, it will be error, and the error is "Undefined index: contract"

Can you help me with this?
Thanks before

Comment: I already add my form code

Comment: Just curious, did you exactly write `$post` or `$_POST`.

Comment: @SarojShrestha sorry for my typo, I used $_POST

Comment: @LodeweykAndri could you do `print_r($_POST)` in `do_insert.php` and let us know what showing there.

Comment: @Phil after check the network, I found Request Method: GET. how can?

Comment: Is the request an AJAX request (`xhr`) or a normal one? Does the page navigate to `do_insert.php` when you click the button or does it stay on the same page? Where are you seeing the error messages; on the main page or in your console?

Comment: Hi @Phil ,
In the same Page, I found the error message in the console.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>

Comment: @SarojShrestha there is nothing happen when Print_r($POST)

Comment: Any update @Phil?

Comment: @Phil I couldn't stop deleting it, as soon as I saw your reputation :D. And, I was trying to run code here. Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `type:"POST",` instead of `method:"POST",`.

`method:` is an alias for `type:` but only since jQuery 1.9